# Remove Jetpack infinite-wrap

Tags: functions, plugin-jetpack, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to remove the infinite-wrap class jetpack adds to posts with infinite scroll turned on because I want to add infinitely loaded posts to a gridded layout.

I found the article here that says to add the theme support stuff to the functions.php :https://trickspanda.com/customize-jetpack-infinite-scroll/

I ended up adding

```
add_theme_support( 'infinite-scroll', array(
    'wrapper' => false,
) );
```

The weird thing is this has no effect. I have jetpack installed as a plugin and turned on infinite scroll the the settings in the dashboard. Am I doing something wrong? This seems like it should be easy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was using the underscores.me theme, I had to look in the 'inc' folder for the jetpack.php file. There is where I had to change the options to get the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

What if you remove the existing infinite-scroll before re-add it?

```php
remove_theme_support( 'infinite-scroll' );

add_theme_support(
    'infinite-scroll',
    array(
        'wrapper' => false,
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out last night. I'm using the underscores.me blank theme to roll my own and found there is a folder called "inc" with a jetpack.php file in there. I modified the options in that file and now it works.